# How could I detect that all module are loaded by Prism v6?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-6

I have a WPF Desktop App  using RadDocking(Telerik Wpf Control) and Prism.Unity v6.1.1 , The Goal  is that I would like to load the layout of the Docking  when all module are loaded.  How could I detect that all module are loaded WITHOUT ovverride InitializeModules() method?
I would like to call my load method() in shell.xaml.cs code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `EventAggregator`.

**Bootstrapper:**

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void InitializeModules()
    {
        base.InitializeModules();
        var eventAggregator = Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<string>>().Publish("ModulesLoaded");
    }
}
```

**MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<string>>().Subscribe(OnMessage);
    }

    private void OnMessage(string s)
    {
        if (s == "ModulesLoaded")
        {
            //load your layout...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to override the `InitializeModules()` method to be able to do something when the modules have been initialized.

Comment: I appreciate that. Good job